# Relative clause "both dynamic and stative examples of which"

Tags: relative-clauses, possessive-of-which

I am simply interested in whether this sentence is in correct English. Especially, I am unsure about the use of the relative clause in italic.

> The specular reflexions of the glass beads, *both dynamic and static examples of which occur in the image sequence*, were a real issue for the correlation algorithm to produce accurate results.

Maybe I can give this question a better title, suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Instead of looking only at *of which*, see it as *examples of which occur* then it will make sense. The sentence seems to be grammatically correct. From **The Medical and Physical Journal**  *Both the viscera, and the members, however, often suffer from these two species of transformation, examples of which are furnished by every part of the human body*

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly grammatical and normal for fairly formal writing. In a less formal setting (eg in an article about this research in a popular science magazine) it would be better reworded to avoid the complex embedding.